# How attach event in componet inside a slot

Tags: polymer-3.x

I create a web component like this:

```
class P3ELayout extends PolymerElement {

     static get template() {
         return html`
              <slot name="app"></slot>;
         } 
    }

    tapButton(evt) {
         console.log(evt);
    }
}
```

In my index i create this component:

```
<body>
<p3e-layout>
    <div slot="app" >
        <app-header-layout fullbleed>
            <app-header reveals>
                <app-toolbar>
                    <div main-title>P3E</div>
                    <paper-icon-button icon="icons:account-circle" on-click="tapButton"></paper-icon-button>
                </app-toolbar>
            </app-header>
            <div class="layout-container layout-horizontal">
                <div class="layout-vertical layout-flex-auto layout-content">
                    content
                </div>
            </div>
        </app-header-layout>
        <app-drawer id="settingDrawer" align="right" swipe-open>
            setting-drawer
        </app-drawer>
    </div>
</p3e-layout>
</body>
```

I expected to attach on the on-click event of the button but tapButton is never trigger. Can i attach on the component event inside the slot?

Comment: @A Visalli , I think you are trying to reach the target in a long way. Instead, just add a `paper-icon-button` in your `p3e-layout` element in order to fire an event. Or if you try to explain more explicitly. What you are trying to do, may find a better way.

Comment: your slot layout looks fine. can you paste the error u r seeing in console. Most probably., check imports., write `on-click` method before `static get template`., just set `console` in on-click method... I can help you out if u can brief me the error from console.